# How to enter a nuclear reaction?

Tags: formatting, physics, writing

Sometimes the simplest things are the most difficult, I need to make a presentation, and I thought to do it in *Mathematica*, I wanted to do a demonstration too, well...this is the Rutherford's equation

[image]

Can this be done in *Mathematica*?

Comment: This can certainly be done. But in general, I would suggest to use $\LaTeX$. See also here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384610/how-to-write-a-chemical-formula

Comment: I don't know if you can do nuclear reactions in Mathematica but there is `IsotopeData` and you can do things like decay chains: https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/graphs-and-networks/plot-isotope-decay-networks.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps this is close to what you want:

```
id = IsotopeData[#, "FullSymbol"] &;

id["Nitrogen14"] + id["Helium4"] -> id["Oxygen17"] + id["Hydrogen1"]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Or to hold the order of the terms, i.e., to prevent them from being placed into canonical order,

```
Inactive[Plus][id["Nitrogen14"], id["Helium4"]] -> 
 Inactive[Plus][id["Oxygen17"], id["Hydrogen1"]]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** The original (simpler) form requested can be obtained using

```
id2 = IsotopeData[#]["FullSymbol"] &;
```

Jason B pointed out in a comment that `id2` can also be written as

```
id2 = EntityValue[Entity["Isotope", #], "FullSymbol"] &;
```

For comparison,

```
id /@ {"Nitrogen14", "Carbon15", "Helium4", "Carbon12", 
  "Oxygen17", "Hydrogen1", "Carbon14"} // Sort
```

[image]

```
id2 /@ {"Nitrogen14", "Carbon15", "Helium4", "Carbon12", 
  "Oxygen17", "Hydrogen1", "Carbon14"} // Sort
```

[image]

Comment: what is the "canonical order" here?

Comment: @NooneAtAll - the canonical order appears to be alphabetic. The original order {"N", "He"} changed to {"He", "N"}; and {"O", "H"} changed to {"H", "O"}.

Comment: it could also be from lightest to heaviest. Is there a place where the order rule is stated?

Comment: @NooneAtAll - Lightest to heaviest does seem to be the order. Look at `Sort[id/@{"Nitrogen14", "Carbon15", "Helium4", "Carbon12", "Oxygen17", "Hydrogen1", "Carbon14"}]`. Canonical order is "documented" in the "Details" section of the documentation for `Sort`

Comment: Just so it's clear what function is being called, I would replace the definition of `id2` with `id2 = EntityValue[Entity["Isotope",#],"FullSymbol"] &` , and use `EntityValue` in general instead of `IsotopeData`